# Angular Material not getting executed in browser

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am designing a UI section using Angular Material but my browser does not reflects the code, specifically `<mat-form-field></mat-form-field>`. I have tried updating my angular and npm.

I took 3 approaches to solve it but the problem persists:

1.I used the `ng update` in the terminal which gave me the following result: "We analyzed your package.json and everything seems to be in order. Good work!" 
2.`npm update` which resulted in "found 0 vulnerabilities".
3. I restarted my machine.

Comment: Can you give us an stackblitz version of your code cuz we also need to check the NgModule of the app

Comment: This is the link to my project on stackblitz.
https://add-angular-material-vqlvvs.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: There are several issues with your code. I updated dependencies to latest versions and moved template to different for better IDE experience. It works now. Check it in StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-wbuseu

---

**Old Response:**

You need import `MatFormFieldModule` into your `NgModule`.

**NgModule:**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Standalone component (v14 or later):**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [ MatFormFieldModule],
    template: `
        .....
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: I have made the imports but still not able to see Form Fields.

Comment: There are several issues with your code. I fixed it, you can see it here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-wbuseu